# opencv CV_32FC1 convert to 4 channels

Tags: opencv

I need to convert CV_32FC1 to 4 channel with opencv:

```
// Get inputs and setup output.
  const auto& input_img = cc->Inputs().Tag(kImageFrameTag).Get<ImageFrame>();
  const auto& mask_img = cc->Inputs().Tag(kMaskCpuTag).Get<ImageFrame>();

  cv::Mat input_mat = formats::MatView(&input_img);
  cv::Mat mask_mat = formats::MatView(&mask_img);

  //The mask_mat here is in CV_32FC1 format, I need to convert it to CV_32FC4, 4 channels.

  cv::Mat channels[4];
  cv::split(mask_mat, channels);  

  //...
```

The mask_mat here is in CV_32FC1 format, I need to convert it to CV_32FC4, 4 channels.

Comment: Either cv::cvtColor(in, out, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGRA) or sts::vector<cv::Mat> channels; channels.push_back(in); 4 times ; out = cv::merge(channels);

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I'm newbie, thank you very much